# Messages not being generated before dependent package

Tags: ros, catkin-make, generate-messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am having a very frustrating problem. I have a package `pac_industrial_robot_driver` that uses messages declared in another package `ros_opto22`. However, I cannot get the dependency recognised by the `pac_industrial_robot_driver` `CMakeLists.txt` file.

The error message:

```
[ 31%] In file included from /home/controller/catkin_ws/src/pac_industrial_robot_driver/lib/PacIndustrialDriver.cpp:8:0:
/home/controller/catkin_ws/src/pac_industrial_robot_driver/include/PacIndustrialDriver.hpp:32:38: fatal error: ros_opto22/valve_command.h: No such file or directory
```

Clearly it is not finding the include file.

```
# Create executables and add dependencies.
foreach(p ${ALL_EXECS})
    add_executable(${p} ${${p}_SRC})
    add_dependencies(${p} ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ros_opto22_EXPORTED_TARGETS ros_opto22_gencpp ros_opto22_generate_messages_cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${p} ${ALL_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} industrial_robot_client simple_message industrial_utils)
endforeach(p)
```

Note the inclusion of `ros_opto22_gencpp` and `ros_opto22_generate_messages_cpp`.

I also have the following earlier on in the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES pac_industrial_robot_driver
  CATKIN_DEPENDS ros_opto22
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

and

```
## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

as well as a having `ros_opto22` listed under the `find_package` call.

**I am very frustrated with this**, not in the least because there does not seem to be a single definitive guide to solving this problem. What is the best way to go about solving this problem? I can run `catkin_make` twice but that only masks the problem. I want `catkin_make` to run properly first time every time even after deleting everything in the `build` and `devel` directories under my `catkin` workspace.

Kind Regards
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192758/messages-not-being-generated-before-dependent-package/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2014-09-16**:
I think what you need is `generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ros_opto22)`

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-16**:
I believe `generate_messages` is not for using message files from *another* package.

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2014-09-17**:
True, my mistake. I meant `add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} <msg_package_name>_cpp)`. We use this in order to ensure the necessary messages are compiled before the current package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT2: This line in your CMake code can be simplified:

```
add_dependencies(${p} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)
```

These are the only two things you would ever need to do, `catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS` is never empty, which is important because `add_dependencies` will fail if you give it variables which do not exist.

I can't see why your code is not compiling on the first try from what you have shown us, is it where you could share these two packages with us, maybe even in private?

---

EDIT: I just noticed that you are actually using the right target dependency options here, let me look at it again. Sorry for the noise below.

---

I'm sorry you're finding this frustrating, I can sympathize. Unfortunately to resolve this, you need to have a target dependency on the message generation. We cannot do this automatically because catkin does not override the `add_executable` macro in CMake. Though we've tried to mention it everywhere we think it might be run into, if it is lacking from some piece of the documentation, please feel free to update it yourself or at least point someone to the deficient docs.

This extra step for depending on message generation targets is described in the ROS Tutorials:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes-1

It is also mentioned in the sort of cookbook for catkin `CMakeLists.txt`:

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Important_Prerequisites.2BAC8-Constraints

And in the official genmsg documentation (genmsg is the package which generates messages):

http://docs.ros.org/api/genmsg/html/usermacros.html

There is also a answer on this site, which I think you've found:

http://answers.ros.org/question/111136/fatal-error-file-massageh-not-found/?comment=192767#comment-192767

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-16**:
I think the issue here is that the messages from package `ros_opto22` are not being found by the package `pac_industrial_robot_driver`  containing the above CMakeLists, even though the `add_executable` macro contains `ros_opto22_generate_messages_cpp` as a dependency

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-16**:
You're right, in this case he needs `${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}`

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-16**:
Oh, I guess I missed the part where he is using the EXPORTED TARGETS already, let me update my answer.